# In react, how do I close a popup confirmation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, eslint

The popup confirmation should be closed when any part of the screen outside the popup is clicked. But the popup remains on the page even after the outside is being clicked. And it keeps displaying " Line 2:8:  'Backdrop' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
Line 3:8:  'Modal' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars" in my terminal. Here is my code.

#Todo.js

```
import {useState} from 'react'

import Modal from './Modal'

import Backdrop from './Backdrop'

function Todo(props){
const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOPen] = useState(false)

  function deleteHandler(){
    setModalIsOPen(true)
  }

  function closeModalHandler(){
    setModalIsOPen(false)
  } 

   return <div className='card'>
   <h2> { props.text} </h2>
   <div className='actions'>
   <button onClick={deleteHandler}>Delete</button>

   </div>
   {modalIsOpen && <Modal/>}
   {modalIsOpen && <Backdrop onCancel={closeModalHandler} />}


 </div>
}

export default Todo;
```

#Backdrop.js

```
import propTypes from "prop-types"

function Backdrop(props){

    return <div className='backdrop' onClick={propTypes.onCancel}/>
}

export default Backdrop
```

#Modal.js

```
function Modal(){
    return <div className='modal'>
        <p>Are you sure?</p>
        <button className='btn-alt'>Cancel</button>
        <button className='btn'>Confirm</button>
    </div>
}

export default Modal
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think your `Modal` has props problem

```
return <div className='backdrop' onClick={propTypes.onCancel}/>
```

It should be like this `onClick={props.onCancel}` because you're using `props` instead of `propTypes`.

Secondly, for the warning you get

> Line 2:8: 'Backdrop' is defined but never used no-unused-vars Line 3:8: 'Modal' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

If you're using eslint, you need to check your `.eslintrc` should have some configs like below

```
"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
]
```

If it's not there you can install it

```
npm install eslint@7 --save-dev
npm install eslint-plugin-react --save-dev
```

Comment: Did it help you? @EmmanuelJoseph